# How to send objects to remote akka actors in an asymmetric system

Tags: scala, akka, erlang-otp

In Programming Erlang by Joe Armstrong, section 16.1, the author describes a method for hot code swapping with Erlang's OTP framework. I'd like to be able to do this with Akka.

Given an asymmetric Akka system where Comp A and Comp B have established remote communication.
A would like to send function f of type Int => Int to comp B to be processed. However, f's definition does not exist in the classpath of Comp B. Is there anyway to make this work without transmitting the jar file of A in advance and adding it with a custom boot loader (ie. OSGI) ?

Comment: you should be able to do this, but you'll have to read and send the bytecode of the class representing your function and use a custom ClassLoader on the other side of the wire to load and instantiate it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this will work.  If the receiving JVM does not have the anonymous class definition that represents the function to send then you will end up with a `ClassNotFoundException` or something else similar.  I have tried this before without success.  It's pretty similar to a RMI type situation in Java where both sides of the system must have the class definition in place in order to communicate properly.  That's just the nature of the beast when dealing with the JVM (and object serialization) I guess.

Comment: As Steve Waldman commented it should be possible, but remote class loading is not something Akka wants to get into (it’s a can of worms); sending the bytes over in messages and creating a ClassLoader should in principle work, but then you’d have to serialize and deserialize the function by hand.